# Rate of aromatic nucleophilic substitution reaction on ortho and para fluoronitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

**Why** rate of aromatic nucleophilic substitution of *Ortho*-fluoronitrobenzene is greater than *para*-fluoronitrobenzene?

Kindly note question is about why rate of ortho is greater than para position. Not **meta** position.

This is previous year KVPY question but they had not asked reason and just asked comparison of rate.

Comment: I think it's probably due to the inductive effect of the nitro group. The effect is strongest at the ortho position

Comment: Please do not use formatting on the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reaction mechanism of aromatic nucleophilic substitution is as given -

[image]

Source : https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/08/20/nucleophilic-aromatic-substitution-nas/

The rate determining step is the formation of the C-Nu bond, which causes the development of a negative charge on the carbon atom at ortho position to leaving group (fluorine). Presence of electron-withdrawing groups helps to stabilize the negative charge, and hence increase the rate of reaction.

The -NO2 substituent exerts not only a -M effect (resonance) but also a strong -I effect (inductive effect, which pulls the negative charge away from the ring). Inductive effect decreases rapidly as the distance increases, so its effect is much more pronounced for *ortho* than for *para* (Note that the initial negative charge is developed at the *ortho* position). As a result orthofluoronitrobenzene has a higher rate of reaction than parafluoronitrobenzene.